# Fill textbox on my page from the text box in my modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

In my page i have a textbox and a dropdown list, when i select my item number 10 it shows me a modal, in this modal i have a textbox and i'd like to take the information entered by the user and put it in my page texbox when i submit it in the modal.

But can't figure how to do get this information to my textbox on page.

If someone could help, would be nice :) here is my script.

```
$(function () {
    $("#Dropdown1").change(function () {
        //Recupere la value de la liste
        selection = $(this).val();
        //Mettre la valeur du choix de liste.
        if (selection == 10) {
            //Affiche le modal
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
    });
})
```

;

My view (some things have been deleted) :

```
 <h4 class="mb"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Example</h4>
  <div class="form-horizontal style-form">
   <div class="form-group">
       @Html.LabelFor(m => m.X.Y, new { @class = "col-sm-d col-sm-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.X.Y, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.X.Y, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Dropdown1" })
                </div>
```

And i'd like to fill the @Html.textboxfor with wha's inside my modal.

I made this so :

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#X_Y').val($('#Y_X'));
})
```

but still getting [object Object] in my field instead of what's inside the modal.

Comment: Show your view and indicate which textbox is which

Comment: It's done, i can't show all my code.

Comment: You have not shown your modal. What is the textbox in it that you want to get the value of and copy to the `TextBoxFor(m => m.X.Y` ?

Comment: It's a simple texbox just a number value, for example i will enter 1 in it, and want it to be in TextBoxFor(m => m.X.Y

Comment: `$('#X_Y').val($('#yourOtherTextboxID'));`

Comment: $('#X_Y').val($('#yourOtherTextboxID')); So X_Y is my first text box id ? And i add that in my script ?

Comment: You have not shown your script, but yes, when you close the modal, call that code.

Comment: My script is in my subject, i put it inside but when i open the modal the textbox is filled with this automaticaly : [object Object]

Comment: You don't do it when you open the model, you do it when you close the model (after you have entered a value in the modal's textbox).

Comment: Oh yes sorry, so i created another function with this inside, and call it on a onClick inside my button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109424/discussion-between-christian-pliso-and-stephen-muecke).